# How to restart browser in the middle of the test and not loose dependency injection?

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am starting new Chrome xor Firefox browser at the beginning of the test and I register the instance using BoDi. I need to restart browser in the middle of the test.

I can do it but I can't re-register the instance in BoDi, so the old `WebDriver` will be injected in next steps. I can't use `AutoFac` because it doesn't support Specflow 3 nor I haven't found any other DI container that does.

The only solution I found is to split test in two parts so the browser will restart naturally, however this is hacky.

Comment: Are you restarting the browser with an explicit step or internally in a step step definition or page model? What triggers the browser restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class that wraps your web driver, and pass this around to your step definitions. This class will expose a method to restart the browser. Since all other step definitions should be passed this wrapper they should always get the web driver from this wrapper, thus eliminating the need to re-register it with BoDi.

```
public class WebDriverManager
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    public IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new [Chrome|Firefox]Driver(...);
            }

            return driver;
        }
    }

    public void RestartBrowser()
    {
        driver.Quite();
        driver.Dispose();
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

And to register it with BoDi:

```
[Binding]
public class SpecFlowSteps
{
    private IObjectContainer container;

    public SpecFlowSteps(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void RegisterWebDriverManager()
    {
        var manager = new WebDriverManager();

        container.Register(manager);
    }
}
```

And an example usage in your step definitions:

```
[Binding]
public class YourSteps
{
    private WebDriverManager driverManager;

    private IWebDriver Driver => driverManager.Driver;

    public YourSteps(WebDriverManager driverManager)
    {
        this.driverManager = driverManager;
    }

    [When(@"I restart the browser")]
    public void WhenIRestartTheBrowser()
    {
        // Or whatever you call the step
        driverManager.RestartBrowser();
    }
}
```